# How to rewrite a complicated expression in terms of several defined functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, transformation, substitution

I have a long expression in mathematica that contains various unevaluated definite integrals and numerous parameters. I also have other functions whose definitions contain these integrals, and I know my expression can be rewritten in terms of these functions. I cannot get mathematica to rewrite my complicated expression in terms of these defined functions.

I have thus far tried to use mathematica functions 'Solve' and 'Eliminate' to rewrite my expression in terms of certain defined functions, but this has not worked - see below for details.

First, I find the solution to a system of two linear equations by inverting some coefficient matrix A:

```
ln[20]:= equation1 = -Inverse[A] . vector1 // MatrixForm // FullSimplify
```

whose solution is shown in the image below (I was having trouble posting the output code in the code block environment)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quomS.png) (NB: this is my first post so I'm unable to post images since I need at least "10 reputation to post images")

I'm interested in expressing the first element in the vector solution above in terms of the functions X, Y, Z, K, E, Pi, and W, as defined below

```
X[r1_, r2_] := Inactive[Integrate][1/Sqrt[R], {r, r1, r2}];
Y[r1_, r2_] := Inactive[Integrate][r^2/Sqrt[R], {r, r1, r2}];
Z[r1_, r2_] := Inactive[Integrate][(r (LL r - 2 M (LL - a EE)))/(\[CapitalDelta] Sqrt[R]), {r, r1, r2}];
K[k_] := Inactive[Integrate][1/Sqrt[1 - k Sin[\[Phi]]^2], {\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]/2}];
Ee[k_] := Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[1 - k Sin[\[Phi]]^2], {\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]/2}];
\[CapitalPi][z_, k_] := Inactive[Integrate][1/((1 - z Sin[\[Phi]]^2) Sqrt[1 - k Sin[\[Phi]]^2]), {\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]/2}];
W[r1_, r2_] := Inactive[Integrate][( r (r^3 + a^2  EE r - 2 a (LL - a EE)))/(\[CapitalDelta] Sqrt[R]), {r, r1, r2}];
```

My attempt to do this via the function Eliminate is this:

```
Clear[X, Y, Z, K, Ee, \[CapitalPi]];
Eliminate[{expr == equation1[[0, 0]] , X == X[r1, r2], Y == Y[r1, r2], Z == Z[r1, r2], K == K[k], Ee == Ee[k], \[CapitalPi] == \[CapitalPi][z1, k], W == W[r1, r2]}, {M}] // FullSimplify
```

but this doesn't produce the desired result. Instead, the output is

```
Output[34]= Ee == Ee[k] && expr == Symbol && K == K[k] && W == Inactive[Integrate][(r (-2 a LL + r^3 + a^2 EE (2 + r)))/((a^2 - 2 Mr + r^2) Sqrt[(a LL - EE (a^2 + r^2))^2 - (a^2 - 2 Mr + r^2) ((-a EE + LL)^2 + Q + r^2 \[Mu]^2)]), {r, r1, r2}] && X == X[r1, r2] && Y == Y[r1, r2] && Z == Z[r1, r2] && \[CapitalPi] == \[CapitalPi][z1, k]
```

Note that the expected solution is
[Analytical solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xIFd.png) (NB: this is my first post so I'm unable to post images since I need at least "10 reputation to post images")

where the constant E is EE in my code (different from the function E(k)), and z_+, z_{-} are z2 and z1 in code respectively.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to achieve this rewriting of my expression in terms of these functions? I have looked at many responses to questions asked previously on stack overflow but none so far have helped me make progress on this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Since I can't actually see your long expression I cannot be certain that this will help. 1: Using `MatrixForm` can turn an expression into something pretty to look at, but the result almost always cannot be used for any further calculations or manipulation. The same tends to be true of all the other `*Form` functions. Don't use those unless you really know what you are getting into. 2: `Simplify` might help you. `Simplify[biguglyexpr, smallexpr==mediumexpr]` will do lots of transforms to find all `medium` inside `big` and then replace those with `small` See if that can do what you want

Comment: Sorry, fixed a typo in item 2, `=` should have been `==` and For item 2: the "size", which you measure using `LeafCount[expr]`, of `small` MUST BE less than the size of `medium`. You cannot use this trick to replace something small with something bigger. And I have no idea how this trick is going to interact with `Inactive`, I never use that and can't even guess what that might do to this.

Comment: @Bill thanks for the response, I'll see if the items help. In the meantime, you can actually see the long expression by clicking on the link attached to the word "Output" three lines below the first code block - maybe seeing it will make my question more specific.

Comment: I think you are trying to turn big parts of your output back into `K[k]` for example and you start by telling it `K[k_]:=...` That is the opposite of what Mathematica wants to do. It thinks it is supposed to expand all the function definitions until there is nothing left to expand. BUT if I knew `Integrate[3x^3,x]==(3*x^4)/4`and I don't tell MMA and ONLY tell it `Simplify[3 x^4/4+y^2-3,k[3x^3,x]==3x^4/4]` then it returns `-3+y^2+k[3*x^3, x]` I just tried that and it worked. It is actually REALLY lucky because `k[3x^3,x]` is same "size" as `3x^4/4`. Does what I've written here make any sense?

Comment: This makes sense I think - in my "Simplify[]" code block I should clear X,Y,Z,K, E, \[CapitalPi] and W, and then in the simplify function write X[r1, r2]==..., Y[r1, r2]==... and so on, with the caveat that the X,Y,Z,... are smaller than what's on the right hand side of each "==" respectively. However, I tried this and it hasn't produced the correct equation; the output still says "Symbol". Do you have any insight into why the output is "Symbol" / what this means?

Comment: If you can edit your original question and at the bottom of that paste exactly the code that you used in your Simplify along with a description of what you want the result form to be, if that isn't clear from the rest of your post, then I can scrape it off the screen and try to find a way to get it to work for you. As a test, you can then try scraping your own code off the screen and trying it in a fresh start of MMA and see if it does exactly the wrong thing for you. Hopefully that will let both of us be working on exactly the same problem.